# Notepad++ replace a random value with blank

Tags: notepad++, regex

I have an XML file in which I have multiple lines of `Value="(random characters/numbers/symbols)"` for example `Value="fREFG$£$RF43wfr£$32"` of varying string lengths. I am wanting to sanitise this and replace it just with `Value=""`

How would I do this with regex

I got as far as..... find: `Value=\"([0-9]*)\"`

however that doesn't cover characters/symbols

Answer (score 2):

I used the following test data:

```
Value="fREFG$£$RF43wfr£$32" 
Value="fREFGdasdee$$$££♫_+_+ïSAD_+ASDF43wfr£$32"
```

Using `Value="[^"]*"` with Notepad++'s find search mode set to Regular expression works. This can also be used in find and replace.

`[^"]*` Can be put between any known containing characters in your document, in this particular case it was " ".

[image]